# How do I move my cursor in my modified QSpinBox after every number entered in PyQt4?

Tags: python, cursor, pyqt, pyqt4, qspinbox

I have this `QSpinBox` class which is modified to display 3 digits (including zeros).

```
class ThreeDigitSpinBox(QtGui.QSpinBox):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtGui.QSpinBox.__init__(self, *args)

    def textFromValue(self, value):
        return "%03d" % value
```

My problem is every time I select and delete the existing value on the widget, and start keying in, the cursor position mess up my key entering.

Let's say I have just delete everything in the QSpinBox. Then I intend to key in value "314".

(Let me use "|" to represent cursor)

As soon as I key in "3", the box display "003" with the cursor right after the first 0. "**0|03**".

When I continue key in the second digit "1", the SpinBox display "103" with the cursor right after the second digit. "**10|3**"

Due to the position of the cursor placed, my intended number "314" was never entered. Instead it display "1043" after keying in all 3 digits of "314".

How do I make sure so that the cursor is placed at the proper position for me to key in the numbers correctly?

I am using windows XP SP3 with Python 2.7.3 (32bits)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use a parameter of the baseclass [QAbstractSpinBox](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html), [keyboardTracking](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking-prop)

if this is set to false, it won't emit the valueChanged signal before you press enter, or the widget loses focus.

Description from the Qt docs:

> If keyboard tracking is enabled (the default), the spinbox emits the
>   valueChanged() signal while the new value is being entered from the
>   keyboard.
>
> E.g. when the user enters the value 600 by typing 6, 0, and 0, the
>   spinbox emits 3 signals with the values 6, 60, and 600 respectively.
>
> If keyboard tracking is disabled, the spinbox doesn't emit the
>   valueChanged() signal while typing. It emits the signal later, when
>   the return key is pressed, when keyboard focus is lost, or when other
>   spinbox functionality is used, e.g. pressing an arrow key.

[pyqt docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractspinbox.html#keyboardTracking) is as usual pretty useless here.